# Interface is down/down but internet works

Tags: cisco, switch, interface

I am managing a network at my company. A patch panel provides connections to the switch, which is connected to the router.

One of the connections on the switch does not display a blinking green light. However I checked the connection to the patch panel, went to the computer and it is receiving internet.

The only way I can think of this working is if the previous engineer made an error on the blueprint and it is a different desk.

How can an interface be down/down with no blinking green light at the switch, yet deliver internet through it? Is there a mistake or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Do you rely solely on LED blinking to determine the port is "down/down".
Have you checked port status via terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the port status in the management console and the switch's MAC table - likely there's just a documentation error and the port is connected elsewhere. I've also seen mislabeled patch panels.

Comment: Yeah, documentation error is the easy/obvious answer. The device in question is simply conneceted to a different port. The MAC address table will show you which one.

Answer (score 0):

The "down/down" status on the switch interface suggests a layer 1 issue, possibly a faulty cable or port. However, if the connected device is receiving internet, it indicates that the issue might be with the switch port or its LED indicators rather than the actual connectivity. Consider checking the physical cable, trying a different switch port, or inspecting the switch for potential hardware issues.